# Relay Mutation keep giving error if static fragments is enabled

Tags: react-native, relay

Here is my code on my mutation

```
class CreateUserMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

  static fragments = {
    user: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User{
        id
        email
      }
    `
  }

  getMutation () {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{ createUser }`
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      email: 'bondan@something.com'
    }
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on CreateUserPayload {
        user{
          email
        }
      }
    `
  }

  getConfigs () {
    // console.log('getConfigs props', this.props);
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        user: this.props.user.id
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

and this is my implementation on UI

```
  componentWillMount () {
    let mutation = new CreateUserMutation();
    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(mutation);
  }
```

its a simple experiment apps just to check if my mutation is working when the app load

however the i keep getting this error

[user is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo6BK.png)

Please help me what is wrong with the mutation code?